# Castle Windsor: How to register an open generic type for injection using Func<T> and UsingFactoryMethod?

Tags: castle-windsor

I have a generic interface IRepository that has a single concrete generic implementation MyRepository.  I use the following code to register for all possible type T in one go:

```
container.Register(CastleReg.Component.For<typeof(IRepository<>)).ImplementedBy(typeof(MyRepository<>)).LifeStyle.Transient)
```

I have other classes registered that themselves have in their constructor something like this:

```
public SomeClass(IRepository<Person> myRep)
{
   ...
```

The issue with this is that the class SomeClass might have been registered as a Singleton LifeStyle which means the myRep property is resolved once.  In order to have the myRep resolved when it is actually needed I've learnt that I can use the following syntax:

```
public SomeClass(Func<IRepository<Person>> myRepFactory)
```

and then use the following to obtain the actual repository:

```
myRepFactory().DoSomeQuery()
```

Now my issue is with how I tell the container that myRepFactory should be resolved to a factory method that will itself resolve as before?

I thought I could add this to the registration but the registration fails with an ArgumentNullException for a key parameter:

```
container.Register(CastleReg.Component.For(typeof(Func<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(IRepository<>))).UsingFactoryMethod(() => container.Resolve(typeof(IRepository<>))).LifeStyle.Transient)
```

How do I setup the registration so that it allows resolving both `IRepository<Person>` parameter types and also `Func<IRepository<Person>>` parameter types?

Thanks in advance,

Mark

P.S. I'm using Castle.Windsor 2.5.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [TypedFactoryFacility](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Typed-Factory-Facility.ashx) which supports that out of the box:

Comment: I was sure I'd already tried that but I'm mistaken as it works a treat and so simple too.

Comment: Could you give more detail? I don’t see how that solves the problem.

Comment: @DanielCassidy I believe something like: `container.Register(Component.For(typeof(IRepository<>)).AsFactory())` would do the trick.

Comment: @Daniel I thought I'd add (a year late) a little detail: I left the IRepository<> registration as it is in the first code line in the question and merely added the following at container configuration time: container.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();  This was enough to allow constructor DI using either IRepository<Person> or Func<IRepository<Person>> parameter types.